# displaying different text with same id tag jquery

Tags: jquery, html

So what I want my code to do is that when I hover an i element with an certain id I want my jquery to take the text inside the i tag and post it back in an alert. But this only works for the first id so my second one that has id=toolt doesn't get alerted when I hover over it. Is there anyway I can fix this? T

Thanks!

```
<?php
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tooltip</title>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#toolt').hover(function(){
                    //MOUSE ENTERS
                    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'block');
                    var x = $('#toolt').text();
                    alert(x);

                },function(){
                    //MOUSE LEAVES
                    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none');

                });
            });


        </script>


    <style>
        #ppp{
            position:fixed;
            left:200px;
        }

        #tooltip{
                position:absolute;
                z-index:2;
                width:200px;
                padding5px;
                background-color:#A7A7A7;
                font-size:17px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                display:none;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="tooltip">
        Hello fanbois
    </div>

    <p id="ppp">This is a text that has <i id="toolt">Things</i> inside it <i id="toolt">Stuff</i>  </p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need classes not ids. ID is unique identifier and can be used only once.

Change attribute `id` into `class`

```
<p id="ppp">This is a text that has <i class="toolt">Things</i> inside it <i class="toolt">Stuff</i>  </p>
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.toolt').hover(function(){
                    //MOUSE ENTERS
                    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'block');
                    var x = $(this).text();
                    alert(x);
//Here you can use $('#tooltip').text(x); to make text display in the tooltip

                },function(){
                    //MOUSE LEAVES
                    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none');

                });
            });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very, very quick answer!